# How to solve Integrals with natural logs

Tags: integration

How to solve the following integral with natural logs:

$$\int_0^e \frac 1{\ln (x^x)}  dx$$

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Hint:  $\ln (x^x)=x\ln (x)$   But did you really mean $0$ in the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an improper integral which diverges. $$\int_0^e \frac 1{\ln (x^x)}  dx =  \int_0^e \frac 1{x\ln (x)}  dx $$

Upon substitution of $$ u=\ln x$$

We get $$ \int_{-\infty}^1\frac {1}{u}  du =$$

$$\ln (|u| )|_{-\infty}^1 = -\infty$$